# Convert Watin Browser Session to Selenium Browser session? c#

Tags: c#, selenium, watin

I have a  Watin browser session named ie. I've ran into a situation where I need Selenium's help to execute an action. Is there any way to quickly tell Selenium to use the browser associated with Watin session ie? (I'm working in a child thread).

Comment: did you try selenium.selectWindow(windowname);? I think selenium iterates over all the IE running processes and match the win id to get a popup, so it might work for you. (im really not sure). On the other hand, why do you need to combine watin and selenium?